# iOS Universal Links and URL Shorteners

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

We have recently begin to encounter issues with our Universal Link implementation when the UL is accessed via a shortened `goo.gl` URL.

This Works: `https://site.domain.com/Deep/Link`

This does not: `https://goo .gl/fake` -> `302 Redirect` -> `https://site.domain.com/Deep/Link`

Is anyone else experiencing the same thing?

Note: I had to break up the shortened Google URL to keep StackOverflow's editor from yelling at me.

Answer (score 10):

Universal Links are triggered by the URL that is being accessed, and are ignored if a redirect is not triggered by explicit user action. Since `goo.gl` isn't registered to your app (and cannot be, since you don't control it), burying your URL behind a shortened link is bypassing Universal Link detection for the destination domain.

There is no good workaround for this on `goo.gl`. The best option is to set up a URL shortener on a custom domain that you CAN register with your app for Universal Links. Alternatively, [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) or Firebase Dynamic Links could handle this for you, since both essentially set up a custom link shortener on a domain they control for Universal Links on your behalf.

Comment: Thanks. As I thought more about it I started to get the impression that this is what was going on

Comment: But what about my app handling that fake path? I thought about having an API that translates the fake path to a real one when the universal link is triggered and waking up my app. Any other suggestion?

Comment: That is essentially what both Branch and Firebase do. It's a good solution, though probably overkill to build yourself