# Facebook sometimes does not fetch Open Graph tags

Tags: php, ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph, ios-universal-links

I have an iOS app for a public library that shares links to Facebook. The links point to a single domain, which contains a relatively simple PHP script that redirects to three different destination domains based on the linked content (catalog items, calendar events, and user-generated lists). I have it set up like this because I'm using iOS universal links and I don't have control over all of the link destinations, so I need a central location for the apple-app-site-association file.

In this PHP script, I'm attempting to set OG tags dynamically based on the type of content that was shared. Here's the script:

```
<?php

$shareType = $_GET['t'];
$contentId = $_GET['id'];

$base_catalog_url='XXXXXXXXXXXX';
$base_list_url='XXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$base_event_url='XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

if($shareType=='0'){
    $oclc;
    if(strlen($contentId)==8){
        $oclc = 'ocm'.$contentId;
    }

    if(strlen($contentId)==9){
        $oclc = 'ocn'.$contentId;
    }

    $url = $base_catalog_url.'searchCatalog?'.http_build_query(array('clientID' =>'sdIPhoneApp','term1'=>$oclc));
    $resp = simplexml_load_file($url);

    $pageTitle = $resp->HitlistTitleInfo->title;
    $isbn = $resp->HitlistTitleInfo->ISBN;
    $imageURL = 'http://www.syndetics.com/index.aspx?isbn='.$isbn.'/lc.gif&client=XXXXXXX';
    $redirectURL =  'XXXXXXXXXXXX'.$contentId;
    error_log($redirectURL);
    echo '<html>
        <head>
            <meta property="og:image" content="'.$imageURL.'" />
            <meta property="og:title" content="'.$pageTitle.'" />
            <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
            <meta name="twitter:site" content="@acpl" />
            <meta name="twitter:title" content="'.$pageTitle.'" />
            <meta name="twitter:description" content="Allen County Public Library" />
            <meta name="twitter:image" content="'.$imageURL.'" />
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='.$redirectURL.'">
        </head>
     </html>';
}

if($shareType=='1'){
    $url = $base_event_url.http_build_query(array('eventid' =>$contentId));
        $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($response);
    $event = $json[0];
    $imageURL = $event->Image;
    $pageTitle = $event->Title;
    $description = $event->Description;

    if(strlen($imageURL)<5){
        $imageURL = 'https://XXXXXXXXX/appIcon200.png';
    }

    $redirectURL = 'XXXXXXXXXXX'.$contentId;

    echo '<html>
        <head>
            <meta property="og:image" content="'.$imageURL.'" />
            <meta property="og:title" content="'.$pageTitle.'" />
            <meta property="og:description" content="'.$description.'" />
            <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
            <meta name="twitter:site" content="@acpl" />
            <meta name="twitter:title" content="'.$pageTitle.'" />
            <meta name="twitter:description" content="'.$description.'" />
            <meta name="twitter:text:description" content="'.$description.'" />
            <meta name="twitter:image" content="'.$imageURL.'" />
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='.$redirectURL.'">
        </head>
     </html>';

}

if($shareType=='2'){

    $url = $base_list_url.http_build_query(array('listId' =>$contentId,'userKey'=>0));
    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($response);
    $imageURL = $json->coverImageURL;
    $pageTitle = $json->listName;
    $pageTitle = ucwords(strtolower($pageTitle));

    $redirectURL = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";

    echo '<html>
        <head>
            <meta property="og:image" content="'.$imageURL.'" />
            <meta property="og:title" content="'.$pageTitle.'" />
            <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
            <meta name="twitter:site" content="@acpl" />
            <meta name="twitter:title" content="'.$pageTitle.'" />
            <meta name="twitter:description" content="Allen County Public Library" />
            <meta name="twitter:image" content="'.$imageURL.'" />
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='.$redirectURL.'">
        </head>
     </html>';

}

?>
```

So, based on the type of content that was shared, I fetch a page title and image to provide in the OG tags. The redirection always works, regardless of whether Facebook pulls in the tags, but the tags are utilized only about half the time. You can see this in the iOS app. Tags pulled in successfully:

[image]

Tags not pulled in:

[image]

It seems to be random whether the tags are displayed for a given item. In the access logs on my server, when the tags are successfully displayed, I see a line like this:

```
66.220.158.119 - - [09/Sep/2016:09:54:50 -0400] "GET /share.php?t=1&id=76137 HTTP/1.1" 206 3771 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"
```

However, when the tags are not displayed, there's nothing in the access log or the error log. This suggests that Facebook (or the Facebook component in iOS) is not even attempting to read the tags in these cases. Does this mean Facebook mistakenly thinks it has this data cached?

Another interesting tidbit is what happens when I try to debug one of these failed URLs on the Facebook sharing debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/). I'll get an error message along the lines of:

```
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

And when I click "See what our scraper sees for your URL." I get the response "The document returned no data".

The interesting thing is that when I click "Scrape again", it usually gives the same error for the first few times, then after 3 or 4 attempts it suddenly works and the tags are displayed. My first thought there is that this has to do with how I'm dynamically fetching the content for the tags, but as I noted above, in the cases where the tags aren't displayed, the access log shows that Facebook isn't even requesting anything from my server.

Thanks for your help; this has me pulling my hair out!

**UPDATE:** Here's an example URL if you'd like to try it out in the Facebook debugger if you'd like: https://amshare.acpl.lib.in.us/0_930144011

The number after the underscore is the OCLC number of the book, so you could plug in other values there. As I mentioned, after a few scrapes it usually starts working, then later fails to work again, etc.

Comment: Is the base URL (without query params) always `share.php`? I'm not sure whether Facebook considers the appended params when determining what to cache, so that could be causing this oddness.

Comment: Yes, it's always share.php. I suppose I could use a different script for each share type (shareItem.php, shareEvent.php) but it seems like this would suffer from the same basic problem.

Comment: I think you might need to go with unique URLs for every link. If you look at URL shorteners (Bit.ly, Goo.gl, etc.) and other services that rely on per-URL tracking or dynamic routing (HubSpot, HootSuite), they universally do it this way. At [Branch.io](https://branch.io) we do almost exactly what you're describing above, and every link always comes with a unique URL

Comment: If I do that then I can't utilize universal links.

Comment: Should still be able to. Just put all the unique URLs underneath a single directory (e.g., `/share/7ahAs7D`) and then enable Universal Links for everything within that directory.

Comment: I was using tinyurl previously and couldn't make universal links work with this in place. This SO question (answered by you :) ) seems to suggest it's not possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36225871/ios-universal-links-and-url-shorteners

Comment: I think you're right though, if I could make that work with universal links, it might solve the above problem.

Comment: Ah, yes that wouldn't work because you don't control the Tinyurl domain, and can't associate it with your app. You'd need to set up the unique link strings on your own server/domain. You could also give the Branch linking service a try, since it would be able to do this for you

Comment: I'm going to look at some sort of URL rewriting as a possible workaround. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @AlexBauer No luck I'm afraid. I'm rewriting the urls so they look like "http://XXXX/type/idnumber" so every URL is unique, but I still get the same behavior. I'll stick with these URLs because they're shorter, but the original problem remains.

Comment: Hmm, I must throw in the towel then — I honestly don't know what would be causing this

Comment: it doesn't hit your server again because it thinks it's the same resource "A URL with no session id or extraneous parameters. All shares on Facebook will use this as the identifying URL for this article." but i see you tried this approach..  maybe try to remove slashes and change too underscore... as it may still fail under "Bad URL
This URL has extraneous information that changes from user to user, resulting in likes/shares spread across multiple URLs, instead of being aggregated for all users sharing this article." https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags

Comment: Also check your hosting, maybe it's blocking similar requests  sent from bots in short time span with some sort failt2ban software

Comment: @PawelDubiel I have changed the slash to an underscore, but I am still getting the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I could be possible that facebook caches the share.php file and ignores the GET Vars.

you could try to rewrite the URL to a "pretty permalink". Put this in your htaccess file (if you have apache):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^share/(.*)/(.*)$ share.php?t=$1&id=$2 [L,NC]
```

this makes out of **`http://your-url.com/share/4/yeah`** this: **`http://your-url.com/?t=4&id=yeah`**

The $_GET var looks like this:

```
Array ( [t] => 4 [id] => yeah )
```

With this you could solve this problem (if it is REALLY caching). I had a lot of issues with the facebook scraper in the past. sometimes it ignores get vars and it caches like hell...

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior after making this change. Also, I would say it is almost certainly a caching problem of some kind. As I mentioned above, in the cases where the tags don't work, there is absolutely nothing in the access logs. So Facebook is not requesting anything from my server in those cases.

Comment: Have you tried to add the og:url meta tag with extacly the same sharer.php url? (or rewritten, if you inserted my snippet)? It tells FB to scrape the url in it - possibly it could solve your caching problem?

Comment: I've tried this; it results in the same behavior. When I tell it to "scrape again" on the debugger, it seems to be totally random whether it works or not.

Comment: Can you post the url for a share so i can test myself what happens?

Comment: The number after the underscore is the OCLC number of the book, so you could try plugging in other values there. As I mentioned, after a few scrapes it usually starts working, then later fails to work again, etc.

Comment: I checked with curl for the status code: `curl https://amshare.acpl.lib.in.us/0_930144011 -A "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" -I`. I noticed that a lot of my request are failing with this error code: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: amshare.acpl.lib.in.us`. Can you check that you don't have any DNS problems or something else? Very strange behaviour. I think that this is causing your problem because the normal Facebook Scrap works without any problem...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123535/discussion-between-adrian-lambertz-and-james-harpe).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some headers to your response to prevent caching.

Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0