# goo.gl is not working with deeplinks

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, google-url-shortener

I have implemented universal links.

Universal links works fine with the original domain and it opens app straight away on url tap.

But my client wants goo.gl shortening url which causes a problem here and deep links are not responding and not opening the app when url is tapped.

Although I have added goo.gl in my app entitlements.

I am not sure what exactly is a solution.

Please help me if anyone knows.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Universal Links and URL Shorteners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36225871/ios-universal-links-and-url-shorteners)

Answer (score 2):

You can only implement universal links for a domain that you have control over, as universal links require both app and website components to function. Since you don't own the `goo.gl` domain, you won't be able to upload the required `apple-app-site-association` file to that domain.

This is pretty reasonable behavior from a security standpoint--imagine if a competitor decided that *their* app should open links on *your* site?

Comment: This is 100% correct. However, might be worth mentioning the [Dynamic Link short URL options](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-links), since they use a custom subdomain of `goo.gl` that _is_ controlled by Google on the user's behalf, and would accomplish what the OP wants (which is shortened URLs that open the app)

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. OP, please note that this requires you to use Firebase, which may or may not meet your needs.

Comment: Ahhhh, totally assumed the OP was already using Firebase, which I now re-read and see is not the case at all. [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) is also another good option for accomplishing this.